# Creating a wrapper over an open source diff tool

Tags: git, git-diff, meld, kdiff3

I want to write a wrapper over some open source diff tool. 
Say kdiff3. Suggesting the way to do the same.

The diff tool shows as per file what is the diff in the code.
I want it to perform specific task as per my requirement and automatically resolve the conflicts by deleting the code that has caused the conflict.

Comment: OK, what is your question? What did you try? What language do you plan to use?

Comment: I am using json for which I have to merge code. The problem is for eg. I have a button and I have changed its id from btn1 to btn2. What diff tool will show is just the change in id but I want to create a wrapper where I can add more details so that it will be easier for end user to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that kdiff 3 doesn't have api, though you can call it from command line http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html with different options. This doc can help you achieve your goal.